# notarget No matching version found for @firebase/functions-compat@0.3.8

Tags: javascript, firebase

firebase did an update this morning and this dependency is nowhere to be found.

try update

```
"firebase": "^10.3.1",
```

to

```
"firebase": "^10.8.1",
```

is't work.

What else can I try?

I try to limit version to

```
"firebase": "~10.3.1",
```

is work.

Comment: Remove the node_modules directory and reinstall dependencies again sometimes solve the problem, i am not sure here, check that once

Comment: Please edit the question to show the exact steps you're taking.  We should be able to reproduce the issuing using the instructions you provide.  It's not enough to say "it doesn't work" - you should be able to show us what specifically isn't working.  The Firebase SDK shows a [current version 10.8.1 on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase), so it should be OK.